# rails text_field_tag onchange: not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

Hii have an ajax submitted form that only contains a text_field_tag. I want the form to submit as soon as the user starts typing his search string. Bandwidth / lag is not an issue since the app will be hosted in the company's intranet.

I currently have this:

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], onchange: "$(this).parent('form').submit();"%>
```

However it does not submit the form when I start typing in it. Only when I hit enter.

How come?

Comment: Maybe you should use onkeyup: instead. For onchange: I think you must blur the object in order for the event to start

Comment: doesn't work either. Even the blur doesn't work. I need to git enter to submit the form manually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sends an ajax post request after every keystroke:

```
<%= form_tag test_path, remote: true, method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], onkeyup: "$(this).parent('form').submit();"%>
<% end %>
```

Tested and working on Rails 4.1.

Comment: I would add the javascript in a js file apart, is more unobtrusive to me.

Comment: Also, avoid inline java-script instead bind `onkeyup` event on text_field_tag in js file.

Comment: I followed this but my app is processing the request as HTML and I need it to process as JS. Using Rails 6.